# Mongo DB command via SSH

Tags: mongodb, bash, shell, ssh

When doing the following it works fine:

```
local$ ssh remote

remote$ mongo mydb --eval 'printjson(db.test.find({value : {$regex: "string"}},{name:1,_id:0}).toArray())'
```

However, if I try to do the following:

```
local$ ssh remote "mongo mydb --eval 'printjson(db.test.find({value : {$regex: "string"}},{name:1,_id:0}).toArray())'"
```

I get this error:

```
TokuMX mongo shell v2.0.0-mongodb-2.4.10
connecting to: mydb
Thu Apr 21 11:31:03.916 SyntaxError: Unexpected token :
```

What am I missing here?
I know it must be something with escaping or enclosing special chars, but I couldn't figure out how to do it properly.
Your help will be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: The double quotes around `string` close the double quotes just before `mongo`.  Backslash these and you will be fine.

Comment: I tried that as well but still didn't work